# How to Pause your script in selenium untill your Autoit script gets completed?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, autoit

I want Selenium to wait untill and unless Autoit Script is completed.

Right Now whats happening is When I run `TestNG.xml` file it runs all the @Test Priority wise and within 5 sec TestNg output Console Shows all the @Test are Passed.
While my AutoIT scripts are still running parallely in background.

The Code is as Follows:

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void CreateNew() throws Exception
{       
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\CreateNew.exe");       
}

@Test (priority=2)
public void OpenaFile() throws Exception
{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\OpenaFile.exe");
}
```

And the Code of AutoIt file is as Follows:

```
createnew()

Func createnew()
    Sleep(2000)
    Run("Mspaint.exe")
    WinWaitActive("Untitled - Paint")
    Send("!f")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("n")
    Sleep(2000)
    WinClose("Untitled - Paint")
EndFunc   ;==>createnew
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new process for AutoIt and wait for the process to complete. Look at below example.

```
@Test (priority=1)
 public void CreateNew() throws Exception
 {       
   Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\CreateNew.exe");   
   p.waitFor(); 
 }

 @Test (priority=2)
 public void OpenaFile() throws Exception
 {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exeFiles\\OpenaFile.exe");
    p.waitFor();
 }
```

p.waitFor() will make the current Thread to wait for the process.